# Access violation when using shaders in LWJGL 3

Tags: lwjgl, kotlin

I've successfully used LWJGL 2.9.3 in the past and am now giving LWJGL 3.15 a shot in Kotlin.

I had a quad rendering nicely but now I'm using shaders it seems that openGL isn't initialized and I'm not sure why. I look through others' example code and can't figure out why mine isn't working. I've called glfwInit() and GL.createCapabilities()

```
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffd4af32957, pid=14068, tid=0x00000000000026ec

# Problematic frame:
# C  [lwjgl_opengl.dll+0x12957]

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000071bd1d50 is an unknown value
RBX={method} {0x0000000016404640} 'glCreateShader' '(I)I' in 'org/lwjgl/opengl/GL20'
RCX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
```

My best guess is that the problem lies somewhere in one of these two classes:

Main.kt

```
import org.lwjgl.glfw.*
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*
import org.lwjgl.glfw.Callbacks.*
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*
import org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.*
import org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*
import shaders.StaticShader

class Main : Thread(){

private var window: Long = 0
private val width = 800
private val height = 600
private val title = "Swan LWJGL"

private val loader = Loader()
private val renderer = Renderer()
private val shader = StaticShader()

override fun run() {
    init()

    val model = loader.loadToVAO(
            floatArrayOf(
                    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0f,
                    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
                    0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
                    0.5f, 0.5f, 0f),
            intArrayOf(
                    0,1,3,
                    3,1,2))

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

        renderer.prepare()
        shader.start()
        renderer.render(model)
        shader.stop()

        glfwSwapBuffers(window)
        glfwPollEvents()

    }

    loader.free()
    shader.free()
    glfwFreeCallbacks(window)
    glfwDestroyWindow(window)
    glfwTerminate()
    glfwSetErrorCallback(null).free()
}

private fun init() {
    GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set()
    if (!glfwInit()) throw IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW")

    glfwDefaultWindowHints()
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE)
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE)

    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, NULL, NULL)
    if (window == NULL) throw RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window")

    glfwSetKeyCallback(window) { window, key, _, action, _ ->
        if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE)
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true)
    }

    stackPush().use { stack ->
        val pWidth = stack.mallocInt(1)
        val pHeight = stack.mallocInt(1)
        glfwGetWindowSize(window, pWidth, pHeight)
        val videoMode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor())
        glfwSetWindowPos(window,
                (videoMode.width() - pWidth.get(0)) / 2,
                (videoMode.height() - pHeight.get(0)) / 2)
    }

    GL.createCapabilities()
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window)
    glfwSwapInterval(1)
    glfwShowWindow(window)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    println(glGetString(GL_VERSION))
}

companion object {
    @JvmStatic fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        Main().start()

    }
}

}
```

StaticShader.kt

```
package shaders

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.FileReader
import java.io.IOException

abstract class Shader(vFile: String, fFile: String){

private var vID = loadShader(vFile, GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
private var fID = loadShader(fFile, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
private var id = glCreateProgram()

init{
    glAttachShader(id, vID)
    glAttachShader(id, fID)
    //bindAttributes()
    glLinkProgram(id)
    glValidateProgram(id)
}

fun start(){
    glUseProgram(id)
}

fun stop(){
    glUseProgram(0)
}

fun free(){
    stop()
    glDetachShader(id, vID)
    glDetachShader(id, fID)
    glDeleteShader(vID)
    glDeleteShader(fID)
    glDeleteProgram(id)
}

private fun loadShader(file: String, type: Int): Int{
    val src = StringBuilder()
    try{
        BufferedReader(FileReader(file)).useLines { it.map{
            line -> src.append(line).append("\n")
        }}
    }catch(e: IOException){
        e.printStackTrace()
        error("Error reading file")
    }
    val sID = glCreateShader(type)
    glShaderSource(sID, src)
    glCompileShader(sID)
    if(glGetShaderi(sID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE){
        println(glGetShaderInfoLog(sID, 500))
        error("Error compiling shader")
    }
    return sID
}

open fun bindAttributes(){}

open fun bindAttribute(attrib: Int, name: String){
    glBindAttribLocation(id, attrib, name)
}

private fun error(msg: String){
    System.err.println(msg)
    System.exit(-1)
}

}
```

Comment: How about you tell us what graphics hardware you have?

Comment: I've got a Lenovo IdeaPad v310 running a Radeon R5 M430. (Yes I'm overseas without my good computer) I solved my problem :) I appreciate you taking the time to respond, though.

Answer (score 2):

Switch the statements `glfwMakeContextCurrent()` and `GL.createCapabilities()`

`glfwMakeContextCurrent()` creates the context, which needs to happen first.
`GL.createCapabilities()` then retrieves function pointers and checks available extensions, but this needs an active context first.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It's throwing an exception because by constructing the StaticShader class when I declare it in my Main class variables, gl functions are being called by StaticShader's constructor before OpenGL has been initialized in the init() function of my Main class. I moved the initialization of StaticShader until after I'd initialized OpenGL and now it works fine.